# Why won't this while loop have the same usage as the for loop to find factorial of a number in python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and this code:

```
def factorial(n):
  number = 1
  result = 1
  for x in range(n):
    result *= number
    number += 1
  return result
```

works fine to find a factorial of the number n.

However, once I change the code to:

```
def factorial(n):
  number = 1
  result = 1
  while number < n:
    result *= number
    number += 1
  return result
```

it doesn't work as intended when it looks to be the same piece of code (to me at least).

Can anyone enlighten why this 'while' loop does not work the same way as the 'for' loop? Thanks.

Comment: The `for` loop version iterates 1 more time than the `while` loop version. That is because `range` iterates from `0` to `n` but your `while` loop starts basically at `1` then runs to `n`.

Comment: There is a Difference of one in the amount of iterations

Comment: Just add soime print statements within the while loop to print the before/after values of variables, and the loop counter - primitive debugging aid but simple and effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see the difference in what happens:

```py
In [6]: def factorial(n):
   ...:   number = 1
   ...:   result = 1
   ...:   for x in range(n):
   ...:     print(f"multiplying {result} by {number}")
   ...:     result *= number
   ...:     number += 1
   ...:   return result
   ...:

In [7]: factorial(5)
multiplying 1 by 1
multiplying 1 by 2
multiplying 2 by 3
multiplying 6 by 4
multiplying 24 by 5
Out[7]: 120

In [9]: def factorial(n):
   ...:   number = 1
   ...:   result = 1
   ...:   while number < n:
   ...:     print(f"multiplying {result} by {number}")
   ...:     result *= number
   ...:     number += 1
   ...:   return result
   ...:

In [10]: factorial(5)
multiplying 1 by 1
multiplying 1 by 2
multiplying 2 by 3
multiplying 6 by 4
Out[10]: 24
```

We can see that the second loop run 1 less time, this is because range(n) starts from 0, not from 1, so your loop had one more run

Answer (score 1):

`for x in range(n)` iterates from `0` to `n - 1`.

`while number < n` iterates from `1` to `n - 1`, one less iteration.

If you change the `while` to `while number - 1 < n` both loops will be equal.

Answer (score 1):

```
Consider following examples
n = 5
number = 1
for x in range(n):
    print("foo")
    number += 1
```

outputs `foo` 5 times, whilst

```
n = 5
number = 1
while number < n:
    print("foo")
    number += 1
```

outputs `foo` 4 times. If you want to know more search for *off-by-one error*. That is reason why `for` is recommended for usage where you know number of runs a priori.

Answer (score 0):

While loop can be used as follows:

```
def factorial(number):
    answer = 1
    while number > 0:
        answer *= number
        number -= 1
    return answer
```

Comment: Please don't abuse blockquotes for emphasis. They should only be used when you are quoting something.